# Running a C program as root user programatically

Tags: c, macos

I need to create a file under the "/Library/Preferences/" Mac directory. But in Lion only root user have write privilege to this dir.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fileHandle = NULL;
    fileHandle = fopen("/Library/Preferences/v.test", "w");
    fclose(fileHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

this line of code works if I run this code as `sudo ./a.out`. I wants to do the same programmatically.

Thanks!

Comment: if you could do that, anyone could break security, no?

Comment: Why do you need to do this - why not set preferences for each user when they run it - so don't need admin rights

Comment: It's possible if your program read the root password from input. But there's no difference between this way and `sudo ./a.out`.

Answer (score 4):

can you set the executable to setuid? Just `chown` it to `root` and `chmod u+s`.

Comment: `root`. That is clear. But it is a "do once" action, none that would need to be done continuously.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setuid(0)` from C to change your user id to root. The program will need to be owned by root and set as setuid allowed:

```
chown root:root a.out
chmod u+s a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to achieve this (i.e. without manually granting some special rights to the program prior to execution) - and it is good that there isn't. Any such method would be a prime OS security vulnerability. If you could write such a program which takes root privileges, any malware maker could too...

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user to login as root and launch the program when such a privileged work is to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy thing to do but still doable. Search for SMJobBless example from Apple. In general, it sets up launchd daemon which is run in launchd instance owned by root.