# Elevating to root on MacOS to root with C

Tags: c, macos, macos-big-sur

So I have a very simple code snippet, which simply checks if the process is running as root:

```c
int main()
{
    if(getegid() == 80 || setegid(80) == 0){
        printf("We are root\n");
    }else{
        printf("We are not root\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to elevate to root "automatically" by asking the user password through a GUI. Using the terminal (or just asking the user to re-run the program with `sudo`) is [not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174611/running-a-c-program-as-root-user-programatically/7174652#7174652) unfortunately.
Similarly, the answers posed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated) question are also not suitable, as this is using objective C, not C, and requires the Xcode tools, which I would prefer to not have the user have to install. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826088/how-to-run-my-app-with-root-privileges-on-macos) question is closer, but also assumes Objective-C, and the SMJobBless examples do not seem to exist for C(?).

What are my options for achieving elevation to root under the specified restrictions?

Comment: Why are you checking for group 80 (admin)?  This might (or might not) be root.  Check for uid of 0 instead.

Comment: Well, the best way to do this is sudo but you ruled that out.  Can you make the executable setuid root and restrict it to a specific group?

Comment: Not really. My end goal is for this to be distributed as part of a program where users do not have access to the terminal anyways (due to security restrictions).